# C#: Windows Console Application to Windows Service

Tags: c#, windows, service, console

I have a console application that tracks the performance of the computer, and I am trying to make it into a Windows Service. The service installs fine, however when I go into task manager and try to run the service I get **Error 1053: the service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.** In the task manager the service sometimes has a "starting" status, but it will not run. 
On top of that, when I run the console app, I also get an error stating that:  **Cannot start service from the command line or a debugger. A windows service must first be installed** - which I have done.
This is my program class:

```
    public static string ServiceName = "performanceService";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        if (!Environment.UserInteractive)
        {
            PerformanceCounter ramCount = new PerformanceCounter("Memory", "Available MBytes");
        PerformanceCounter cpuCount = new PerformanceCounter("Processor", "% Processor Time", "_Total");
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to view other information...\n");
        Console.WriteLine("CPU and RAM information");
        while (!Console.KeyAvailable)
        {
            double perf = cpuCount.NextValue();
            Console.WriteLine("CPU Performance: " + perf + " %");
```

... Code continues on that calculates the performance and displays it in the console...

```
 }
        else
        {                
            ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
            ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[]
            {
            new ServiceControl()
            };
            ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
        }
}
```

This is my ServiceControl class:

```
public ServiceControl()
    {
        ServiceName = Program.ServiceName;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        OnStart(null);

    }
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        base.OnStart(args);

    }
    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        base.OnStop();
    }

    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        // 
        // ServiceControl
        // 
        this.ServiceName = "performanceService";
    }
```

To install the service I have used both the Project Installer and manual install, just out of curiosity to be honest.

I changed the time limit through regedit, and that did not help.

Please let me know if you need to see additional code.

My question is, am I missing something from the code, that will not allow my service to start?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: There is some constraint like A window service start method execution must complete in few seconds. And I think you have written all your logic inside start method. So, do one thing use a timer and execute your code inside that timer ticker. So that your service can start...

Comment: @AnupamSharma and how should I fix it? Like create a new class, and have all the code needed to do the performance calculation there?

Comment: You should not be calling OnStart from start, that's completely wrong. Besides that, do you have any other code in OnStart?

Comment: @cFrozenDeath, thank you, I will delete the Start() method. No, I do not have any other code in OnStart().

Comment: I'd suggest you to use WaitForStatus in your console application to wait until the service has started, then send a command to start the processing. Also notice that each time you change your service, you will have to uninstall the previous version and install the new one. You should make 2 bats for faster un/installation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for all your help.
The problem was that I had the Start() method in the ServiceControl class and I had my code the other way around in the Program class.

I was supposed to have the code to start the service in the if statement and the performance logic in the else, so that the start method executes quickly, like one of the comments suggested. After clicking start on the service in the task manager, the status changes to "running".

Thank you again.